# JDBC, user defined objects and arraylist of user defined objects

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist

I have created an object reservation, and arrayList of reservations and am using JDBC to work with a database of reservations.  I am able to insert a reservation into the table, but I must input the values of all attributes of the reservation object in main.  However, the database is set to auto generate the reservationID.  My question is how to can I make it so that when I insert into the database, instead of me inputting the reservationID in main that when I insert into the table the auto generated ID is inputted instead.  This is my first time working with databases so im a bit new to this.

reservation:

```
/** The Reserve ID. */
    int ReserveID;

    /** The Room ID. */
    int RoomID;

    /** The Guest ID. */
    int GuestID;

    /** The Stay duration. */
    int StayDuration;

    /** The check. */
    boolean Check;

    public reservation()
    {
        ReserveID = 0;
        GuestID = 0;
        RoomID = 0;
        StayDuration = 0;
        Check = false;

    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new reservation.
     *
     * @param reserveID the reserve ID
     * @param roomID the room ID
     * @param guestID the guest ID
     * @param stayDuration the stay duration
     * @param check the check
     */
    public reservation(int reserveID, int guestID, int roomID, int stayDuration,      boolean check) {
        ReserveID = reserveID;
        GuestID = guestID;
        RoomID = roomID;
        StayDuration = stayDuration;
        Check = check;
    }
```

arraylist of reservations:

```
/** The res list. */
ArrayList<reservation> resList;

/**
 * Instantiates a new reservation collection.
 */
public reservationCollection()
{
    resList = new ArrayList<reservation>();
}

/**
 * Adds the reservation.
 *
 * @param r the r
 * @return true, if successful
 */
public boolean addReservation(reservation r) throws SQLException {
    resList.add(r);
    reservationJDBC.insertReservation(r);
    return true;
}
```

JDBC class insert method:

```
public static boolean insertReservation(reservation newReservation) throws SQLException {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    String insRes = "INSERT INTO " + RESERVATIONTABLE 
            + " (RESERVATION_ID, GUEST_ID, ROOM_ID, DURATION, STATUS) VALUES ("
            + newReservation.getReserveID() + ", "
            + newReservation.getGuestID() + ", "
            + newReservation.getRoomID() + ", " 
            + newReservation.getStayDuration() + ", "
            + newReservation.getCheck() + ")";    


    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(insRes);
        System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");
} catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

main:

```
System.out.println("Hotel Management System - Test 1");

reservationCollection myCollection = new reservationCollection();

boolean on = true;

while(on){
    reservation r = new reservation(45, 34, 56, 78, false);

    if(myCollection.addReservation(r)){
        System.out.println("Success! The reservation has been inserted to database");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed! There has been a problem with inserting reservation to the database");
    }

    on = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for that `RESERVATION_ID` column (to generate the sequence) in the mysql database table and you can look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) on how to set up the `AUTO_INCREMENT` in mysql database table.

Once you have set up the AUTO_INCREMENT, you don't need to pass the column `RESERVATION_ID` and `newReservation.getReserveID()` in your JDBC query as shown below:

```
String insRes = "INSERT INTO " + RESERVATIONTABLE 
            + " (GUEST_ID, ROOM_ID, DURATION, STATUS) VALUES ("
            + newReservation.getGuestID() + ", "
            + newReservation.getRoomID() + ", " 
            + newReservation.getStayDuration() + ", "
            + newReservation.getCheck() + ")";
```

And I strongly recommend NOT to use the above hard codings of the input parameters directly into the sql string (**which are prone to sql injection attacks**), rather use `prepareStatement` `setter` methods as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: okay the table is set to auto increment, but the problem is in the reservation default constructor I set reservationID = 0 and it is over writing the auto generated value.

Comment: What do u mean by overwriting ? Is it in database ,the value is getting overwritten ?